# Enviando apenas o id

Tags: php

Possuo o seguinte formulario

```
</p>
  <p align="center">Nome:
    <input name="nome" type="text" id="nome">
    <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Email:</strong> 
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="45" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Palpites Grupo A <span class="style1">PRIMEIRA</span> Rodada dias 14/06 e 15/06</strong><br />
    <textarea name="palpites" id="palpites" cols="45" rows="2">A X - X B
C X - X D
      </textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Palpites Grupo A <span class="style1">SEGUNDA</span> Rodada dias 19/06 e 20/06</strong><br />
      <textarea name="palpites2" id="palpites2" cols="45" rows="2">A X - X C
B X - X D
      </textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Palpites Grupo A <span class="style1">TERCEIRA</span> Rodada dia 25/06</strong><br />
      <textarea name="palpites3" id="palpites3" cols="45" rows="2">A X - X D
B X - X C
      </textarea>
    <br />
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" >
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

e minha página cadastrar esta da seguinte forma

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db = mysql_select_db('copa');
$query = "INSERT INTO palpites (id,nome,email,palpites,palpites2,palpites3) VALUES ('$id','$nome','$email','$palpites','$palpites2','$palpites3')"; 
@mysql_query($query);
@mysql_close();//fecha conexao


?>


<script>

alert("dados gravados com sucesso") ;

</script>

// volta pra lá

<?PHP

header("Refresh: 0; /bolao/home/palpitar.php");

?>
```

Mas apenas o id esta sendo enviado, ou na verdade sendo colocado de forma automatica pelo mysql, alguem pode me ajudar por favor ?
Att
Alberico

Comment: Você definiu as variáveis `$nome`, `$email`, etc, que utiliza para criar o registro? No código que postou elas não estão definidas.

Comment: Seria bom arrancar esse monte de @ no seu código. Em raras ocasiões isso é bom. E em todas onde é bom, a pessoa tem total controle do que está fazendo. Outra coisa que normalmente não tem em código bem feito é alert de JS via PHP, e com certeza seu header refresh nao é uma solução fácil de debugar (provavelmente tem muitas maneiras melhores de fazer o que você quer sem improvisos desta natureza).

Comment: Anderson boa tarde, não tenho muito conhecimento, como assim definidas ? Pois no banco de dados eu criei da mesma forma.

Comment: O código o HTML está incompleto, qual método você está usando no formulário, GET ou POST?

Comment: já pensou em usar o codeigniter é bem util e vai te ajudar muito

Comment: Caso alguma resposta resolveu seu problema marque-a como aceita, veja como e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1):

**1º MYSQL**

As funções do MySQL se tornara, obsoletas depois de atualizações. Atualmente é usada MYSQLi pelo seu desempenho ser superior e algumas vantagens.
Leia sobre neste link: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php

**2º CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS**

Como forma de garantir mais segurança e melhor manuseio com a DB, deve ser feito uma página a parte para a conexão da seguinte forma.

1 - Crie uma página em php chamada conexao.php. Após criar, adicione sua conexão nesta página.
Ficando assim:

```
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "copa";

//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

if(!$conn){
    die("Falha na conexao: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}       
?>
```

Assim evitando a duplicata de conexões.
   Salve sua conexão onde desejar (De preferência na pasta raiz junto com as páginas para seguir este tutorial corretamente).

**3º FORMULÁRIO**

Você deve primeiramente fazer com que o formulário envie seus dados para o PHP.

no começo da tag , atribua ele como método POST.

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" method="POST">
```

Após atribuir, adicione um nome para seu botão:

```
<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="btnForm">
```

Assim você poderá chamar os dados quando o botão for acionado.

Salve seu formulário onde desejar (De preferência na pasta raiz junto com as páginas para seguir este tutorial corretamente).

**4º INSERINDO DADOS**

Você precisa transferir seus valores de entrada do formulário para dentro do INSERT.

Deste jeito:

```
<?php
include_once("conexao.php"); // Incluir sua conexão com o banco de dados.
include_once("formulario.php"); // Incluir a página do seu formulário.
$btnForm = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnForm', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if($btnForm){
 include_once 'conexao.php';
 $dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

 $inserirBD = "INSERT INTO palpites (nome, email, palpites, palpites2, palpites3) VALUES (
                '" .$dados['nome']. "',
                '" .$dados['email']. "',
                '" .$dados['palpites']. "',
                '" .$dados['palpites2']. "',
                '" .$dados['palpites3']. "'
                )";


$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $inserirBD);
if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
    echo "
        <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/PASTA/formulario.php'>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        alert(\"Dados inseridos com sucesso.\");
        </script>
        "; // Cria um alerta para seu cadastro.
}else{
    echo "
        <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/PASTA/formulario.php'>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        alert(\"Erro ao inserir dados.\");
        </script>
        "; // Cria um alerta para seu cadastro.
}   

}       
?>
```

Lembrando que, quando você cria um id no MySql, você pode colocar para ser AUTO INCREMENT, onde ele vai contando cada vez que você adiciona um novo palpite, tudo automático, não precisando adicionar ele no INSERT do Mysql.

Comment: Na verdade eu tomei um exemplo de uma aplicação minha, onde acabei esquecendo de apagar rsrs

Answer (score 1):

> Não vou me prender ao formulário pois acho que você postou somente parte dele.

<sub>As funções mysql, estão obsoletas, removidas do PHP 7. Utilize mysqli ou PDO.</sub>

**1 - Exemplo em mysqli.**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "copa");

    // Verifique a conexão
    if($connect === false){
        die("ERRO: não foi possível conectar. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    //DEFININDO AS VARIAVEIS
    //Para evitar injeção, a Solução Ideal seria: Prepared Statements,
    // mas para não dificultar seu aprendizado  utilizarei mysqli_real_escape_string
   //que serve para escapar os caracteres especiais e evitar em partes a injeção

   $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_REQUEST['nome']);
   $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_REQUEST['email']);
   $palpites = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_REQUEST['palpites']);
   $palpites2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_REQUEST['palpites2']);
   $palpites3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_REQUEST['palpites3']);

   $query = "INSERT INTO palpites (nome, email, palpites, palpites2, palpites3) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$palpites', '$palpites2', '$palpites3')";
   if(mysqli_query($connect, $query)){
       //echo "Registros adicionados com sucesso.";
       // ou
       //alert, redirecionamento, etccc
   } else{
       //echo "ERRO: não foi possível executar $query. " . mysqli_error($connect);
       // ou
       //alert, etccc
   }

   // fecha conexão
   mysqli_close($connect);

}
?>
```

> o id não se faz necessário na `query` consoante seu comentário `ou na verdade sendo colocado de forma automatica`

**2 - Exemplo em PDO.**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
 try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=copa", "root", "");
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 } catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERRO: não foi possível conectar. " . $e->getMessage());
 }

 try{
    // prepared statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO palpites (nome, email, palpites, palpites2, palpites3) VALUES (:nome, :email, :palpites, :palpites2, :palpites3)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);


    $stmt->bindParam(':nome', $_REQUEST['nome']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_REQUEST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':palpites', $_REQUEST['palpites']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':palpites2', $_REQUEST['palpites2']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':palpites3', $_REQUEST['palpites3']);

    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Registros adicionados com sucesso.";
    // ou
    //alert, redirecionamento, etccc
 } catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERRO: não foi possível executar $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
    // ou
    //alert, etccc
 }

 // fecha conexão
 unset($pdo);

}
?>
```

> `Prepared statements` fornecem uma proteção forte contra a injeção SQL , porque os valores dos parâmetros não são incorporados diretamente dentro da seqüência de consulta SQL.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda de todos !

Comment: RESOLVIDO       OBRIGADO