# Limitar envio do mesmo email no formulario?

Tags: php

Possuo este formulario

```
<form method="POST" action="/bolao/home/selecoes/russia/cadastrar.php">
<label>
<label>
<div align="center">Nome</div>
</label>
<div align="center">
  <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
  <br>
</div>
<label>
<div align="center">Email</div>
</label>
<div align="center">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  <br>
</div>
<div align="center"><br>
</div>
  <div align="center">
  <div align="center"><br />
    <strong>Palpites Grupo A <span class="style1">PRIMEIRA</span> Rodada dias 14/06 e 15/06</strong><br />
    <textarea name="palpites" id="palpites" cols="45" rows="2">RUSSIA X - X ARABIA SAUDITA
EGITO X - X URUGUAI
      </textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Palpites Grupo A <span class="style1">SEGUNDA</span> Rodada dias 19/06 e 20/06</strong><br />
    <textarea name="palpites2" id="palpites2" cols="45" rows="2">RUSSIA X - X EGITO
URUGUAI X - X ARABIA SAUDITA
      </textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Palpites Grupo A <span class="style1">TERCEIRA</span> Rodada dia 25/06</strong><br />
      <textarea name="palpites3" id="palpites3" cols="45" rows="2">RUSSIA X - X EGITO
ARABI SAUDITA X - X EGITO
      </textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar Palpites" id="cadastrar" name="cadastrar" />
  </div>
  </form>
```

E meu cadastrar.php

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$palpites = $_POST['palpites'];
$palpites2 = $_POST['palpites2'];
$palpites3 = $_POST['palpites3'];
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db = mysql_select_db('copa');
$query_select = "SELECT nome FROM palpites WHERE nome = '$nome'";
$select = mysql_query($query_select,$connect);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($select);


        $query = "INSERT INTO palpites (nome,email,palpites,palpites2,palpites3) VALUES ('$nome','$email','$palpites','$palpites2','$palpites3')";
        $insert = mysql_query($query,$connect);

?>
<script>

alert("Seus Palpites Foram Gravados Com sucesso.") ;

</script>

// volta pra lá

<?PHP

header("Refresh: 0; http://localhost/bolao/home/palpitar.php");

?>
```

Eu gostaria de saber como limitar para que uma pessoa nao envie o formulario com o mesmo email.

Comment: Por favor coloque um [Exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que possamos dar uma resposta mais adequada.

Comment: Foi corrigido minha pergunta.

Comment: Se eu entendi você quer que o email seja uma chave única (não pode ter dois iguais), então antes de cadastrar os dados do formulário você precisa buscar no banco se existe um email ja cadastrado com o valor enviado no formulário

Comment: Exato @GuilhermeCostamilam.

Comment: Aceitar uma resposta é importante pois deixa claro aos demais usuários que seu problema está resolvido, e como foi resolvido. Ao mesmo tempo, recompensa o autor da melhor resposta por ter resolvido seu problema. Saiba como aceitar uma resposta em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1):

```
$query_select = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM palpites WHERE `email` = '".$_POST['email']."'") or exit(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query_select)) {
    exit('Email já existe');
}
```

> mysql_num_rows() retorna o número de linhas em um resultado. Este comando é valido apenas para o SELECT.

<sub>Como já foi dito na sua pergunta [Enviando apenas o id](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280955/enviando-apenas-o-id/280988#280988) as funções mysql, estão obsoletas, removidas do PHP 7. Utilize mysqli ou PDO.</sub>